# Lisp (null (QUOTE NIL)) returns NIL

Tags: lisp, null, nested-lists

I am new to lisp and I'm trying to a simple check to see if a list is empty.  For test purposes i created this test function:

```
(defun test (list)
  (if (null (caddr list))
      (make-node 1)
      (caddr list)))
```

if uses the `make-node` function defined as:

```
(defun make-node (atm)
  (cons atm `(`() `())))
```

when running `(make-node 6)` I get:

`(6 (QUOTE NIL) (QUOTE NIL))`

which is what I want.

i then call `(test (make-node 6))` which i then get:

```
(QUOTE NIL)
```

which is the `(caddr list)` from test.  if you run `(null (QUOTE NIL))` you get `T` which is what i want to get but when i run it from the given test function i receive `NIL`.

So my question is why when i check if this is null why do i get `NIL` instead of `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you evaluate `(null (quote nil))`, `(quote nil)` is evaluated, resulting in `nil` being used as the argument for the function `null`.

However when you evaluate something like `(null (function-returning-quote-nil))`, `function-returning-quote-nil` is evaluated, resulting in the list `(quote nil)` which is then used as the argument for the function `null` without further evaluation.

Compare to the difference between

`(null (quote nil)) ; => t`

and

`(null '(quote nil)) ; => nil`

Comment: Thank you this made it easy for me to understand.  Is there a way to de-quote it? or do you know of how i can get about checking if the inner list is empty?

Comment: De-quoting is done by `eval`, but solutions avoiding `eval` is normally bettter. I suppose that Sylvester's suggestion about changing `make-node` solves your problem, but otherwise you could use the test `(and (eql (first (third list)) 'quote) (not (second (third list))))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(CADDR '(6 (QUOTE NIL) (QUOTE NIL))) ; ==> (QUOTE NIL) or  just 'NIL
```

The list with the two symbols `QUOTE` and `NIL` are not equal to `NIL`. Only `NIL` is equal to `NIL`. eg.

```
(DEFPARAMETER TEST 'NIL)
TEST ; ==> NIL
(NULL TEST) ; ==> T
```

This works since 'NIL gets evaluated to NIL and assigned to TEST. TEST gets evaluated to NIL and it's CLs NULL value. However:

```
(DEFPARAMETER TEST2 ''NIL)
TEST2 ; ==> 'NIL or (QUOTE NIL)
(NULL TEST2) ; ==> NIL
```

A list with two elements QUOTE and NIL, famously displayed as `'NIL`, is NOT `NIL`. Only `NIL` is `NIL`.

**EDIT**

After looking at your comments about unquoting I'm pretty sure you want this as `make-node`:

```
(defun make-node (atm)
  (cons atm '(() ())))

(test (make-node 6)) ; ==> (1 NIL NIL)
```

There is no such thing as unquoting in a data structure and unless you actually want the symbol `quote` in your data there is no sense in having quotes inside something quoted. (Half truth since there is, but it involves macros)

Comment: Thank you This is the same thing as the one that i checked for the answer.  I thought the other was a little easier for me to understand thank you though